# How can I switch between a set of different strings using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I switch between a set of different strings using geometry nodes with the configuration below?

Example, display Hello World followed by say How Are, You Today, Hope Ok...etc

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! You could use the node `Switch` (set to *String*).

Comment: Now that you've clarified your question, do I understand correctly: you want to combine a particular string (that doesn't change) with a number that follows it (that changes incrementally)?

Comment: Clarified again, the string doesn't have to be related... but I would want to use the switch node to move between the set of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you chain 3

[image]

this is how you chain 4

[image]

etc.

For an animation you can do this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Many Thanks! @shmuel